# Java Norwegian decimal separator different in Java 6 and 7

Tags: java, localization, locale, java-7, java-6

The following snippet behaves different in Java 6 than Java 7:

```
final Locale locale = new Locale("nb", "NO");
System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage()); // Norwegian Bokmål

final DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
System.out.println(dfs.getDecimalSeparator());   // Java 6: .
                                                 // Java 7: ,
```

Why is that? Is this change documented somewhere?

Comment: Which is the correct one?

Comment: According to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Norwegian/Numbers, Java 7 should be right. Perhaps a bug fix?

Comment: Yes, Java 7 is correct. But even so, this seems like a breaking change so I am surprised that I am unable find any mention of this change anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JDK 6 and JRE 6 Supported Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html) and [JDK 7 and JRE 7 Supported Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html), the correct/supported syntax for selecting Norwegian Bokmål is "no"/"NO".

`new Locale("no", "NO")` gives the correct result under both Java 6 and Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 had a number of issues regarding `Locale`s, and this may well be one of them. Certainly, the correct separator for the Norway locale is `,`.

The [Oracle bug database](https://search.oracle.com/search/search?search.timezone=-60&search_startnum=&search_endnum=&num=10&search_dupid=&exttimeout=false&actProfId=0&q=norwegian%20locale&group=Bug%20reports&sw=t&search_p_main_operator=all&search_p_atname=&adn=&search_p_op=equals&search_p_val=&search_p_atname=&adn=&search_p_op=equals&search_p_val=) does show quite a few bugs related to NO locale...

Answer (score 0):

## CLDR

In [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later, the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)-based implementations of Java switched to using locale data obtained from the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium)’s [*Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)*](http://cldr.unicode.org/) (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository)) by default.

This switch provides much richer locale data than previously seen in Java. And this switch may mean that you see a **change in behavior** for some aspects of some locales.

See: [*JEP 252: Use CLDR Locale Data by Default*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252)

## COMMA in Java 10

When I run this code:

```
    System.out.println( "java.version: " + System.getProperty( "java.version" ) );

    final Locale locale = new Locale( "nb" , "NO" );
    System.out.println( locale.getDisplayLanguage() ); // Norwegian Bokmål

    final DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols( locale );
    System.out.println( dfs.getDecimalSeparator() );
```

I get the COMMA character.

> java.version: 10.0.2
>
> Norwegian Bokmål
>
> ,